# Подскажите приложения для конвертирования php+html/javascript/css в android файл?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Подскажите приложения для конвертирования php/html/javascript/css в android файл?

Comment: вопрос надо было ставить по другому - `а есть ли вообще такие программные средства?`...на который можно было бы ответить - нет.

Comment: Я только что нашёл одно к Visual Studio, после того, как задал вопрос -Apache Cordova. Они то есть-я уверен, просто поискать нужно. Может кто-то посоветует уже использованные варианты?

Comment: А что такое "android файл"?

Comment: ну apk файл сделать. Что б на телефона отображалось всё то же, что в браузере, но была программа. Ну это я абстрактно говорю-конечно свои нюансы. но хотя бы самое элементарное хочется сделать

Answer (score 1):

есть такие программы, к примеру

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) и из [Хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/company/arcadia/blog/257749/)

Кросс-платформенная мобильная приложение - **PhoneGap/Cordova**.

Используются такие технологии, как HTML5, CSS3 и Angular.js. Grunt применяется в качестве task manager’а, позволяющего упростить и ускорить выполнение рутинных задач. Все сборки компилируются локально во время процесса разработки

Comment: Спасибо. На др форуме посоветовали ещё ionic framework. Вы не сталкивались с ним и какие отличия от PhoneGap?

Comment: я не знал о ionic но она оказывается лучще. Просто PhoneGap один из первых из этих технологий. но Ionic лучще. проверьте тут http://stackshare.io/stackups/xamarin-vs-phonegap-vs-ionic